# Issues with private variable methods and classes

Tags: java, class, methods

I am attempting to write a class that contains 2 private variables, however whenever I attempt to compile I am given error:

> `<identifier>` expected for both setx and seti methods.

```
class complex
{
    private double x;
    private double i;
    public void setx(x1) {x=x1;}
    public void seti(i1) {i=i1;}
}
```

Comment: write as `setx(double x1) { x= x1}`
likewise was another

Comment: Thanks! I completely overlooked that!

Answer (score 2):

You have to write the data type as well (`double` in this case):

```
public void setx(double x1) {x=x1;}
public void seti(double i1) {i=i1;}
```

Actually the most Java way I recommend you is using the keyword `this` that refers to an instance variable. Moreover according the conventions name any class with a capital letter:

```
class Complex {
     private double x;
     private double i;

     public void setX(double x) {
        this.x=x;
     }

     public void setI(double i) {
        this.i=i;
    }
}
```